# What is the relation between force of infection and infection rate?

Tags: model, epidemiology, epidemic-curve

There are different models to define the SIRD/SEIRD models of infection, for instance in one manual:

```
dS/dt = S - (α/N)SI
```

where `S` is the number of susceptible people, `I` the number of infected people, `N` the total population, and `α` the **rate of infection**.
In another manual, the same compartment is defined by:

```
dS/dt = S - λS
```

where `λ` is the **force of infection**.
Since the two formulae point to the same object (the decrease of susceptible people, dS/dt), it should be possible to merge them:

```
S - (α/N)SI = S - λS
(α/N)SI = λS
αI/N = λ
```

Is this equation correct?

Can either `α` or `λ` be calculated from epidemic curves?

For instance, it is also reported that

```
λ = βI
```

where `β` is the number of effective contacts per unit time. Could `β` be derived from epidemic curves?

Also, it is possible to derive the **growth of infection** `Λ` from an epidemic curve by deriving the slope of the regression line passing to the early, exponential cases of infection. How is `Λ` related to `λ`?

Is `Λ` the same as `α`?

Comment: Is your 1st equation presented missing an 'S' on the last term?

Comment: Note: d[(ln(S)] / dt = 1-  Lamba,   which is a likely clue to answer your question by examining the ln of the exponential growth.

Comment: Sorry, there was indeed a missing S; corrected. Is Lambda Λ or λ? How do I relate d(ln(S))/dt to α? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

(This is growing too long to post as a comment...)

Well, if `λ=βI`, as you mention, then your two equations are exactly the same, with `β=α/N`, both `α` and `β` being constants. (Beware that N, the total population, includes the number of deaths, e.g. `N = S + E + I + R + D`, so it is a constant.).

The second equation's presentation is ambiguous, though, as it presents under a constant name (`λ`) something that is definitely **not** constant, as it depends on `I`. I suggest using only the first one, which is a lot clearer.

To estimate `α` or `β`, you have to use modelization and calibration.

The **growth of infection**, in the S(E)IRD model, is, in good logic, the derivative of I, `dI/dt`, whose value is `(α/N)SI` in SIRD, and `εE` in SEIRD (`ε` being a constant, the  multiplicative inverse of the incubation period).

`dI/dt` is definitely not a constant either. Maybe you were looking for the *initial* growth of infection ?